# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Tags: object, nullpointerexception, null

Estoy intentando crear un ViewPager con TABS dentro de una de las opciones de un Navigation Drawer en Android studio, me sale este error como si estuviera apuntando a null:

Código Java dentro del método onCreateView:

```
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contenedor, container, false);
    View parent = (View) container.getParent();

    if (appBar == null){
        appBar = parent.findViewById(R.id.appBar_id);
        pestanas = new TabLayout(getActivity());
        appBar.addView(pestanas);

        mViewPager = vista.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_id);

        llenarViewPager(mViewPager);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        });
        pestanas.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }
    return vista;
}
```

Exactamente el error está en estas dos lineas de código, según el Logcat:

```
pestanas = new TabLayout(getActivity());
appBar.addView(pestanas);
```

Archivo del app_bar_main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Error mostrado en el Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.navdrawer4.fragments.ContenedorFragment.onCreateView(ContenedorFragment.java:72)
```

Espero puedan ayudarme y ver cual es mi fallo. se los agradeceré mucho.

Comment: ¿Haz podido encontrar solución al problema?

Comment: Hola! disculpa la demora y si! encontré la solución al problema al día siguiente de publicado jajaj bueno de todas maneras lo pongo para el que le pueda ocurrir lo mismo.                                                                                                   
    vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contenedor, container, false);
    View parent = (View) container.getParent();                                           
Solo se tenía que cambiar el ...getParent() ... por el ...getRootView()

Comment: Ahora la explicación es que al poner  getParent() este método devuelve al Padre instanciado y en el caso que no exista decuelve NULL. Algo así fue lo que averigué. getRootView() es la solución a este problema!